# betrayal at house on the hill crystal ball and used items

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Is a used item (lucky stone, angel feather, etc) returned to the deck after use or is it completely out of the game.  The rules say "discard this item after you use it".

I ask because with the crystal ball it can make a difference.  Can I use the crystal ball to retrieve a "discarded item" to put it on top again?

Our thought was that its possible to go through all the items so we should put discarded (used items) on the bottom of the deck...especially if you got the crystal ball early and use it many times during a game?  maybe its not possible to go through all the items, but it seems like it would have to be possible.  Or maybe discarded items are only returned to the game after all items are used?

Comment: No. "Discarding" and "place on the bottom of the deck" are rarely synonymous, and only when the rules make them so explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the rules [here](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules2/BetrayalAtTheHouseOnTheHill-rules.pdf) there are instructions for discarding rooms tiles.

> If you go through the whole stack of room tiles, shuffle the tiles you set aside in a discard pile

With that in mind I would handle all discards (of room tiles cards etc) into a discard pile for each and shuffle again if the draw deck for them runs out.  I couldn't see anything in rules about discarding to bottom of deck so that doesn't feel correct.

Comment: The item and event decks are large enough that you shouldn't run out. The issue with the room deck is that cards are discarded if you can't play them so it is easy to go through the entire deck.

Comment: Your probably right.  I've not played the game in maybe 5 years so didn't recall size of decks.  I just thought it seemed unlikely that a discard would be to bottom of a deck unless explicitly stated in a games rules

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but I don't think it's possible to actually exhaust either deck in the vanilla game. There's 22 items and 45 events vs 44 room tiles + Entrance Hall.